# adding grid lines to quantmod indicator & conditional coloring

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using quantmod with the chart_Series and add_TA new functions.
i got a custom made indicator and i want to visualize it. 
i have two problems

1.add grid lines at specific values (same as RSI, 0.2 . 0.8) - just vertical lines on the indicator frame. i know how to add lines to the main graph but cant figure out how to add them to the indicator frame.

2.conditional coloring for an histogram indicator (`type='h'`). lets say that for a value over 0.7 the bar will be green and under red. I've tried `ifelse` in the col parameter of add_TA but got weird results and error messages.

ps, i tried looking at the code of `add_RSI`,`add_MACD` but i couldn't find my solution.

Thanks.